# Obtain delays array from timestamp array

Tags: python, sqlite, numpy

I want to calculate the variance of delay arrivals between signals. Each time a signal comes, a timestamp is registered in the 'time' field of the Logs table of my SQLite database. So I solve the problem the following way:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT time FROM Logs')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
x = numpy.array(rows[:-1])
y = numpy.array(rows[1:])
z = y - x
print "Var  = ", z.var()
```

That gives me the correct value. But... the solution uses two numpy arrays (z stores the delay between one signal and the previous, to be sure: len(z) = len(y)-1 ). I wonder if there is a "numpy" elegant way to do this with only one array, and without iterate over all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `np.diff` function.

```py
import numpy as np

# example data
rows = np.r_[:10]

z = rows[1:] - rows[:-1]
print(z)
#[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]


z = np.diff(rows)
print(z)
#[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```